# Can https and http communicate with each other?

Tags: http, https

I am suddenly curious and ask. I am a novice developer and the following is the sentence I wrote about my situation.

My client is https and my backend server is http, but I can communicate.

However, when the client (https) and socket (http) try to communicate, the communication doesn't work and I get a "mixed content" error.

The backend and the client communicate, but why can't the client and socket communicate? I want to know the reason.

Also, can you ignore "your connection is not private" which happens when using https?

- If you create a socket with https and communicate with the client, it works normally.
- My English is not good. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: It's not clear what the connection between your HTTPS client and your HTTP socket actually is, but I'm assuming a websocket?  In any event, the majority of modern browsers will not permit mixed-mode use in any circumstances.  If it's a websocket, you must implement WSS (which is really easy!) to secure the connection and allow communication to occur

Comment: @Martin I am using socket.io, not websocket. For websocket's wss, do I need to issue a certificate?

Comment: You are using a websocket - socket.io using an underlying websocket for transport.

Comment: Yes you will need a SSL certificate in order to run a socket over HTTPS

Comment: @Martin I have a question. In fact, when using HTTPS, do I need to issue separate certificates to the client (HTTPS) and socket (HTTPS) for authentication? Or can I authenticate with one certificate?

Comment: You can use the same certificate but only if the FQDN of the certificate is valid for both